# Have two CSS of same element make inline one work

Tags: css, blogger

So I have a CSS for .status-msg-body  My blog is hosted in Blogger platform and in that a CSS file is there which cannot be removed. That CSS file contains a CSS for.status-msg-body but I want to change it so I have put an inline to my blog. But that does not works it still shows the CSS specified in the file provide by Blogger by default.

Comment: Idiots Idiots everywhere !important :P Do not open your mouth if you don't know the full thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `!important` property to override those css styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try including `!imporant` in every line of your css class.

For instance if you have

```
.status-msg-body
{
   color:Red;
}
```

and you want it blue, add this class

```
.status-msg-body
{
   color:Blue!important;
}
```

This will override the existing style.